# After using a meyers reset I cannot figure out how to make my ul display horizontally

Tags: html, css

Here is my code:

```css
.navbar-container {
  width:100%;
  display:inline-block;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar-container">
    <ul>
     <li><a href="gmail.com">Gmail</a></li>
     <li><a href="googleimages.com">Images</a></li> 
     <li><i class="material-icons">apps</i></li>
     <li><i class="material-icons">notifications</i></li>
     <li><i class="material-icons">account_circle</i></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I've even tried without the reset and its not doing what I wanted. i'm a little stumped.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_lists_menu

Answer (score 1):

If you want your `<li>`'s to display horizontally, then add `display: inline-block;` to them.

```css
.navbar-container {
  width:100%;
  display:inline-block;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar-container">
<ul>
    <li><a href="gmail.com">Gmail</a></li>
    <li><a href="googleimages.com">Images</a></li>  
    <li><i class="material-icons">apps</i></li>
    <li><i class="material-icons">notifications</i></li>
    <li><i class="material-icons">account_circle</i></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Youre the man! Thanks, I guess I assumed it would target the child elements.